# Highcharts and jquery .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

i have a problem or a question. (sorry for my english, i'm french).

I use Hightcharts to show a lot of charts on one page (~55 charts) and create them  consume a lot of time.
that's why, i want to keep my charts, i don't want to recreate them after change page and redisplay them later.
I make a jsfiddle.example to simulate what i want. http://jsfiddle.net/huhWj/2/

Simple htlm page

```
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
<button id="button">Set new data</button>
<button id="buttonGet">Get container</button>
<button id="buttonSet">Set container</button>
<button id="Empty">Empty container</button>
```

javascript

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {  renderTo: 'container'    },
series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6,     54.4]        
}]
});

var containerData='';
var toggle=0;

// the button action
$('#button').click(function() {

if (toggle%2 == 0) {
  chart.series[0].setData([129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4] );
} else {
  chart.series[0].setData([29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4] );
}
toggle++;
});

$('#buttonGet').click(function() {
  containerData=$("#container").html();
});

$('#buttonSet').click(function() {
  $("#container").html(containerData);
  chart.series[0].setData([129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4] );
  chart.redraw();
});

$('#Empty').click(function() {
  $("#container").empty();
});
```

First, the "Set new data" button show the active chart. Then the "Get container" capture the div contant. 
Now, if I empty the container with "Empty container" button (simulate change page with jquery .load()), and fill it with "Set container", then the chart appear to be inactive. 
My question is how i can activate div container whith chart  ?
I tryed setDate or redraw but nothing seems ok.
Do you have an idea ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm just wonder why you need to get html container, instead of initialize new chart based on json / configuration?

Comment: because, create all charts are very long on ipad and then, once calculated I prefer to keep them in memory instead to recreate